# Rails 5: merging existing custom user table (scaffolded) with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, merge, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

Happy Xmas friends,

I have a Designer table (Scaffolded) where I create users manually and add posts for them.  I created all users with their Twitter username.

.....com/designer/jonive

Now I want to open twitter sign up functionality with Devise and I was wondering how I can merge my Designer table with Devise User so that when someone signups,

- if it matches with an existing designer name I added earlier, it would move posts for the user’s control (edit/delete)
- If not, it would just create as new user.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Apparently I could use any existing table for Devise. I just added Devise required fields to Designer table and added devise_for :designers to routes.rb